# Why an I2C device driver doesn't appear in /sys/bus/i2c/drivers?

Tags: drivers, kernel, raspberrypi

Starting from an image ubuntu-18.04.2-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) I'm trying to add the ad525x_dpot I2C driver which was not enabled during the build of the kernel.

I've taken `ad525x_dpot.c`, `ad525x_dpot.h`, `ad525x_dpot-i2c.c` from the corresponding linux source to make a DKMS package.

dkms.conf:

```
PACKAGE_NAME="ad525x_dpot"
PACKAGE_VERSION="0.10"
MAKE[0]="make all KVERSION=$kernelver"
CLEAN="make clean"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="ad525x_dpot"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/drivers/misc"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m := ad525x_dpot.o ad525x_dpot-i2c.o
KVERSION := $(shell uname -r)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The module `ad525x_dpot` can be loaded by `modprobe` and it shows in `lsmod` but not in `/sys/bus/i2c/drivers`. There are some warnings in syslog.

```
ad525x_dpot: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
ad525x_dpot: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Why doesn't it show in `/sys/bus/i2c/drivers`?

I've tried to load a similar kernel module `ad799x` that comes with the kernel. It appears in `/sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ad799x` (no devices are defined to use the `ad799x`, so it's not related to the device tree or the board config).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to split `ad525x_dpot.o` and `ad525x_dpot-i2c.o` into two DKMS packages to have two separate kernel modules.